# Concourse: Trigger a job with a HTTP request

Tags: git, continuous-integration, concourse

I am trying to trigger a Concourse job with a web hook on my Git server. Following this [issue on Github](https://github.com/concourse/concourse/issues/331) I found an [endpoint definition](https://github.com/concourse/atc/blob/d54a0cc5ce9a9b9aefb7db4aaca077cb3caf2dd5/routes.go#L110). So I tried

```
curl http://10.20.30.101:8080/api/v1/pipelines/helloworld/resources/resource-tutorial/check -X POST
```

where `helloworld` is the name of my pipeline and `resource-tutorial` is the name of the resource for which I want to trigger a check.

But Concourse returns

```
404 page not found
```

What am I doing wrong? Can someone point me to the correct endpoint?

Comment: there seems to be a new endpoint: https://github.com/concourse/atc/blob/master/routes.go#L126

Answer (score 5):

For now there is web hook token for resource:
https://concourse-ci.org/configuring-resources.html#webhook_token

`/api/v1/teams/TEAM_NAME/pipelines/PIPELINE_NAME/resources/RESOURCE_NAME/check/webhook?webhook_token=WEBHOOK_TOKEN`

You can add web hook here:
`https://github.com/<username>/<repo>/settings/hooks/new`

Answer (score 4):

After some investigation and with help from the very supportive [concourse slack channel](https://concourseci.slack.com), I figured out the following solution (which doesn't allow triggering a job via HTTP GET request but is a good start).

First create a new team as [described in the documentation](https://concourse.ci/teams.html#creating-teams) (go for the basic auth solution):

```
fly set-team -n my-team \
  --basic-auth-username ci \
  --basic-auth-password changeme
```

Now generate a authentication token with:

```
curl -u foo:bar http://<CONCOURSE HOSTNAME>:<CONCOURSE PORT>/api/v1/teams/my-team/auth/token

{"type":"Bearer","value":"... VERY LONG TOKEN..."}
```

You can now trigger a build by using the `VERY LONG TOKEN` as a cookie with:

```
curl -v --cookie "ATC-Authorization=Bearer VERY LONG TOKEN" \
  http://<CONCOURSE HOSTNAME>:<CONCOURSE PORT>/api/v1/teams/my-team/pipelines/<PIPELINE NAME>/jobs/<JOB NAME>/builds -X POST
```

Now the job is being triggered.

Comment: Did this work for you ? I am not able to send the post request to trigger the pipeline . This is my code

Comment: import requests

cookie = {'ATC-Authorization': 'Bearer eyJhbG3hVo1KXsg2Ce6-xlew'}

r = requests.post('http://192.168.100.4:8080/api/v1/teams/main/pipelines/mm/jobs/job-test-app/builds'
, cookies=cookie)
dir(r)
print r.text

Comment: 4.0.0 seems to ship with a new login system. 
What worked for me was `curl -v 'http://localhost:8080/api/v1/teams/main/builds' -H 'Authorization: Bearer VERY LONG TOKEN` with the token extracted from ~/.flyrc (having logged in via fly before).