# Can we trigger concourse job with HTTP request?

Tags: slack, slack-api, concourse

I would like to configure my slack outgoing webhook such that it can trigger concourse job over http.  Is there a way that we can trigger concourse jobs via http requests instead of manually clicking on job from web UI?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Concourse: Trigger a job with a HTTP request](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823945/concourse-trigger-a-job-with-a-http-request)

Answer (score 1):

concourse has a feature where you can trigger pipelines via HTTP if you use a webhook token

https://concourse-ci.org/resources.html#resource-webhook-token

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can apparently trigger a [concourse](https://concourse.ci/index.html) job via HTTP request as pointed out in this [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41823945/concourse-trigger-a-job-with-a-http-request) on Stackoverflow.

However you would need to implement an intermediary script (or Slack app) that receives the request from Slack and then triggers the concourse job accordingly. That would not work with a simple [outgoing webhooks](https://api.slack.com/custom-integrations/outgoing-webhooks).

Also please note that Outgoing Webhooks are now outdated. Better use either a custom bot (based on [Events API](https://api.slack.com/events-api) or [RTM API](https://api.slack.com/rtm)) or a [slash command](https://api.slack.com/slash-commands) to trigger them. The former is more flexible and powerful, the latter more easy to implement. I would advise to look into all mentioned concepts to see which bets fits your requirements.